# Multiple conditional ANDs in SQL WHERE

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, java-8

I am currently using a String in Java to run a SQL statement

```
String fruitName = "apple";
String colorOfFruit = a < b ? null : "red";
String sizeOfFruit = c > d ? null : "big";

String sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE fruit = ? " +
 if (colorOfFruit != null) sql += "AND color = ? ";
 if (sizeOfFruit != null) sql += "AND size = ? "
 sql += "ORDER BY fruit";


int i = 1;
PreparedStatement stmt = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(sql)
stmt.setString(i++, fruitName);
if (colorOfFruit != null) stmt.setString(i++, colorOfFruit);
if (sizeOfFruit != null) stmt.setString(i++, sizeOfFruit);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Is there any way I can convert this to a SQL query that I can run with a CallableStatement in Java? I was thinking of creating a stored procedure, but I am not sure how I would conditionally have the `AND` statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @fruitName NVARCHAR(50),
    @colorOfFruit NVARCHAR(50),
    @sizeOfFruit NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE fruit = @fruitName
    -- add an and statement here if @colorOfFruit is not null
    -- add another and statement here if @priceOfFruit is not null
    ORDER BY fruit
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `AND`/`OR` logic e.g.

IF *the parameter is null* OR *the parameter = the column value* e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE fruit = @fruitName
-- add an and statement here if @colorOfFruit is not null
and (@colorOfFruit is null or color = @colorOfFruit)
-- add another and statement here if @sizeOfFruit is not null
and (@sizeOfFruit is null or Size = @sizeOfFruit)
ORDER BY fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is the best, because it allows the SQL optimizer to choose the best access plan.

I would however do it using ternary conditional operators, and remember to use try-with-resources:

```
String sql = "SELECT *" +
              " FROM my_table" +
             " WHERE fruit = ?" +
           (colorOfFruit == null ? "" :
               " AND color = ?") +
           (sizeOfFruit == null ? "" :
               " AND size = ?") +
             " ORDER BY fruit";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    int paramIdx = 0;
    stmt.setString(++paramIdx, fruitName);
    if (colorOfFruit != null)
        stmt.setString(++paramIdx, colorOfFruit);
    if (sizeOfFruit != null)
        stmt.setString(++paramIdx, sizeOfFruit);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to use stored procedure because the actual sql I am using is very long. I just created a small sample for the question. Thank you for commenting though.

Comment: @lzdyzydy Why does size of SQL statement matter?